# java.lang.IllegalStateException: RelativeLayout at android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar.getDecorToolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

App crashes when add Textview to Relativelayout programmatically

**Error Message** :   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity : java.lang.IllegalStateException: RelativeLayout at android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar.getDecorToolbar

***Note  :***  It works fine when Activity extends **FragmentActivity**. But extends **AppcompactAcitivty** app is crashed.

Code

```
   TextView bt = new TextView(getContext());
    bt.setText(" " + id);
    bt.setId(++id);
    bt.getId();
    bt.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.annotation_circle));
    //  bt.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    bt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //  showDialog();
            ToastHandler.newInstance(getContext()).mustShowToast(defString(annotations.getComment()));
        }
    });
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(xdevice, ydevice, 0, 0);
    bt.setLayoutParams(params);

    if(bt.getParent()!=null)
        ((ViewGroup)bt.getParent()).removeView(bt);
    if(  paint_rlay.getChildCount() <= 0)
    {
        if(bt.getParent()!=null)
            ((ViewGroup)bt.getParent()).removeView(bt);
        paint_rlay.addView(bt);

    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < paint_rlay.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            if (!checkCollision(bt, paint_rlay.getChildAt(i)))
            {
                if(bt != paint_rlay.getChildAt(i))
                {
                    if(bt.getParent()!=null)
                        ((ViewGroup)bt.getParent()).removeView(bt);
                    paint_rlay.addView(bt);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: on which line you are getting error?

Comment: what is your app theme (in your manifest) and what is the theme listed in your styles folder?

Comment: paul_hundal    Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: @Amy    paint_rlay.addView(bt);  it works fine  when extending FragmentActivity.

Comment: @JPn try my posted answer

Answer (score 0):

set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

And not forgot to set below property in your theme.

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
 TextView bt = new TextView(getContext());
```

with

```
 TextView bt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
```

And also if you want to use actionbar in activity extending AppCompatActivity, then use it using toolbar and not actionbar.